# HD at 100% after booting

Tags: windows-8, boot

Since some time ago, task manager shows that the HD of my PC is running at 100% after booting, slowing considerably their performance.
After 5 to 10 minutes, disk activity fall down until usual values, and de PC runs fine.
I've tried to disable some services as BITS, Windows Update, Superfetch,..., antiviruses programs, and other program that runs at booting time, but all has been ussesless.
I add an screen capture of task manager after booting.
¿Any idea about this problem?
[Taskman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Rrk.jpg)